# What do these errors mean? (GWT,GAE,Java,JIQL)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm using Jiql to connect to datastore on GAE, but when I try to open db connection and execute a query I get the errors below.

Question is, is it because EntityNotFoundException class is missing or is it because one of the entities in the datastore is missing?  Since I'm totally new at this can somebody please explain the error output?

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.baytex.zoopreel.client.services.StartupService.startSession()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/EntityNotFoundException
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
    at com.baytex.zoopreel.server.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:28)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/EntityNotFoundException
    at org.jiql.jdbc.jiqlConnection.<init>(jiqlConnection.java:59)
    at org.jiql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at com.baytex.server.db.connector.PMF.get(PMF.java:31)
    at com.baytex.zoopreel.server.StartupServiceImpl.startSession(StartupServiceImpl.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    ... 34 more
[ERROR] 500 - POST /zoopreelgwt/startup (localhost) 57 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Service method 'public abstract void 

com.baytex.zoopreel.client.services.StartupService.startSession()'

threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

would seems to be a good place to start, other than that... provide more information if you need better help

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/4596) might well be the solution to your problem.